# How to set Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker to set empty field by default?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm  working  a date picker using Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker. My  challenge is to  set the input field of the date picker to  empty field by  default.

Let me show u the input  field i have used .

```
<td>
  <div>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" id='txtDate' ng-model="personalDetail.date" is-open="personalDetail.isOpen" close-text="Close" ng-click="open($event, personalDetail)" name="datefilter" value="" />

  </div>
</td>
```

And my  script

```
  $scope.personalDetails.forEach(function(personalDetail){
    personalDetail.date = new Date(personalDetail.date);
  });

  $scope.open = function($event, personalDetail) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    personalDetail.isOpen = true;
  };
```

I'm using it  in the html  table with  ng-repeat . But  what  i need is to  show the date field empty untill i set the respective date. Please help  me from this.

Comment: You are binding the control to the field personalDetail.date, so it will display whatever date is present in that value. Setting value="" probably wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td>
  <div>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" id='txtDate' ng-model="personalDetail.date" is-open="personalDetail.isOpen" close-text="Close" ng-click="open($event, personalDetail)" name="datefilter" value="" />

  </div>
</td>
```

Your controller should be

```
$scope.personalDetails.forEach(function(personalDetail){
    //personalDetail.date = new Date(personalDetail.date);//sets the value to the control
    personalDetail.date = !personalDetail.date || new Date(personalDetail.date).toISOString() == new Date('1/1/1900').toISOString() 
        ? '' // Date is null, undeclared, or default value
        : new Date(personalDetail.date);
  });

  $scope.open = function($event, personalDetail) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    personalDetail.isOpen = true;
  };
```

Comment: @anilchean :) Happy to help you.! btw, can u share ur fb id?

Comment: It is worth to say, that problems will arise if you need to use the datepicker directive inside a form with validatation. Angular UI datepicker does not accept an empty model as correct and therefore the form will resul invalid. I faced this problem when my datepicker was *optional* and not initialised to a date inside the form.

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm checking the date value for a NULL or default value (1/1/1900) before I actually set the scope property.
$scope.myDate = !$scope.myDate || new Date($scope.myDate).toISOString() == new Date('1/1/1900').toISOString() ? '' : new Date($scope.myDate);

Comment: @wloescher I didnt get your question.

Comment: @Aravind - not a question, just adding some additional info to your answer (by checking for a default date value).

Comment: @wloescher you can edit the answer with update header. I will approve

Answer (score 1):

Change from

`personalDetail.date = new Date(personalDetail.date);`

to

```
personalDetail.date = "";
```

like `$scope.personalDetail={
            date: ""
            }`